# jQuery sortable an item table on td

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Muj6w/

Well, i need to "drag'n'drop" the line on my table, but no the "td", and yes, the "span" on my table

Sample:
I need move span "value1" to a empty td on column [e,s][1-3](or change the posision, but not grouped). How i can do it?

And need too move from line1 to line2, but not line3 or line4. line[x] -> line[x+1] || line[x-1]

PS: Sorry my poor english

The fiddle code:

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>somedoid</td>
        <td>e1</td>
        <td>s1</td>
        <td>e2</td>
        <td>s2</td>
        <td>e3</td>
        <td>s3</td>
        <td>sum1</td>
        <td>sum2</td>
        <td>sum3</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!-- LINE 1 -->
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">line1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sortable-line">
        <td rowspan="2"><span>value1</span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span>value2</span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span>value3</span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span>value4</span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span></span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>sum1</td>
        <td>sum2</td>
        <td>sum3</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- LINE 2 -->
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">line2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sortable-line">
        <td rowspan="2"><span>value1</span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span>value2</span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span>value3</span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span>value4</span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span>value5</span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span>value6</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>sum1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>sum3</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- LINE 3 -->
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">line3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sortable-line">
        <td rowspan="2"><span></span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span></span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span>value3</span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span>value4</span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span></span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>sum1</td>
        <td>sum2</td>
        <td>sum3</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- LINE 4 -->
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">line4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sortable-line">
        <td rowspan="2"><span>value1</span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span>value2</span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span>value3</span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span>value4</span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span></span></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>sum1</td>
        <td>sum2</td>
        <td>sum3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

JS:

```
$('tr.sortable-line').sortable({
    connectWith: '.sortable-line',
    cursor: 'move',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    items: 'span'
});
```